# What information can be reversed engineered from the StateRef's received by a non-validating notary?

Tags: blockchain, corda, consensus

A non-validating notary receives inputs in the form of [Corda StateRefs](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.contracts/-state-ref/index.html). What information can be reversed engineered from a *StateRef* and what additional information would an attacker need to be successful in doing so?

For more context, please see the answer to the question, [In Corda, what data is sent to a non-validating notary service?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47388690/960184) posted by @joel which explains that the inputs in the form of *StateRefs* are sent to a non-validating notary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deduce the following information from a `StateRef`:

1. That the transaction with identifier `StateRef.id` has at least `StateRef.index` outputs
2. That all the `StateRef`s with the same `StateRef.id` were produced by the same transaction

You cannot deduce anything about the contents of the state.